# Why doesn't my AJAX.ActionLink create the button?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Two partial pages with very slight differences give two different results.

The page that does work:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<p>
    <strong>@ViewBag.Legend</strong>
</p>
<br />
@(new HtmlString(ViewBag.LessonText))
<br />
<p>
    @*create AJAX link for next lesson*@
    @{string linkTxt = "Next Lesson";}
    @Ajax.ActionLink(linkTxt,
    "_ShowLesson",
    new { id = ViewBag.nextLesson },
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "lessonText",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        HttpMethod = "GET"
    },
    new { @class = "button is-small is-success" })
</p>
```

And the page that does not work:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<p>
    <strong>@ViewBag.Legend</strong>
</p>
<br />
@(new HtmlString(ViewBag.LessonText))
<br/>
<p>
    @if (ViewBag.lastLesson)
    {
        <a class="button is-small is-warning" href="~/DCLessons">Last Lesson in DC Basics</a>
    }
    else
    {
        @*create AJAX link for next lesson*@
        string linkTxt = "Next Lesson";
        Ajax.ActionLink(linkTxt,
                        "_ShowLesson",
                        new { id = ViewBag.nextLesson },
                        new AjaxOptions
                        {
                            UpdateTargetId = "lessonText",
                            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                            HttpMethod = "GET"
                        },
                        new { @class = "button is-small is-success" });
    }
</p>
```

The only difference is the addition of the @if else code. Debugging shows the code does drop through to the else but the button with the AJAX Link does not show on the page.

Surely I am missing something simple here, but have not found it yet. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
        @*create AJAX link for next lesson*@
        string linkTxt = "Next Lesson";
        Ajax.ActionLink(linkTxt,
                        "_ShowLesson",
                        new { id = ViewBag.nextLesson },
                        new AjaxOptions
                        {
                            UpdateTargetId = "lessonText",
                            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                            HttpMethod = "GET"
                        },
                        new { @class = "button is-small is-success" });
```

The fix was related to the AJAX.ActionLink itself. In an @if else code block you don't need the @ character Like this line in the orignal code
'''
    @{string linkTxt = "Next Lesson";}

```
The AJAX.Actionlink does require the @ no matter what. Not sure why it didn't throw and exception. 

This is the final code:
```

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<p>
    <strong>@ViewBag.Legend</strong>
</p>
<br />
@(new HtmlString(ViewBag.LessonText))
<br/>
<p>
    @if (ViewBag.currentLesson == ViewBag.numLessons)
    {
        <a class="button is-small is-warning" href="~/DCLessons">Last Lesson in DC Basics</a>
    }
    else
    {
        @*create AJAX link for next lesson*@
        string linkTxt = "Next Lesson";
        @Ajax.ActionLink(linkTxt,
        "_ShowLesson",
        new { id = ViewBag.nextLesson },
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            UpdateTargetId = "lessonText",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            HttpMethod = "GET"
        },
        new { @class = "button is-small is-success" });
    }
</p>
```